While building in Jenkins, the build fails with error
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
> Task :clean
> Task :compileJava
> Task :processResources
> Task :classes
> Task :resolveMainClassName
> Task :bootWar
> Task :war
> Task :assemble
> Task :compileTestJava
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses

> Task :test FAILED

ArtGalleryApplicationTests > initializationError FAILED
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError at SpringExtension.java:381

1 test completed, 1 failed

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///var/jenkins_home/workspace/gallery_mona/backend/art_gallery/build/reports/tests/test/index.html

* Try:
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

BUILD FAILED in 29s

This is error message and down here is my build.gradle.
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

}

bootWar {
    enabled = true
    archiveFileName = "ROOT.war"
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    // JPA, 스프링 시큐리티, 웹(톰캣)
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'

    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.0.2'

    // DB
    implementation 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:3.2.0'
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:6.5.2.Final'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'

    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'

    // Test
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude module: 'junit'
    }
    testImplementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-test"

    // JUnit
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.2'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.2'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}


My application.properties and ApplicationTest code just in case.
spring.application.name=art_gallery

# Local DB
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/dbname
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=****

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true


# Spring Security
#spring.security.user.name=admin
#spring.security.user.password=admin
#spring.security.user.roles=USER, ADMIN

# Swagger
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui
springdoc.api-docs.path=/api-docs
springdoc.swagger-ui.disable-swagger-default-url=true
springdoc.swagger-ui.display-request-duration=true
springdoc.swagger-ui.operations-sorter=alpha

# server image saving route
#file.dir: home\image

package com.example.art_gallery;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = ArtGalleryApplicationTests.class)
class ArtGalleryApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}

I'm working on this error for a week and still couldn't find any clue. Assumption is that, the @Value in the code is not registered as bean while testing and causing error, so I should use mokito. But I never used it before and it's first time I get this error. If you need any other info about my project, please let me know.
I tried changing version, JUnit dependency injection, checking versions of JUnit and hibernate etc.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

It specifically tells you the file and line it fails on, and what it fails with (a referenced method not existing). I don't see that test - or is that the last code block? It certainly doesn't have 381 lines.

Yes. Suprisingly, that's the last code block.
